# How to auto organize the scripts used by custom Facelets components?

Tags: javascript, include, facelets, serverside-javascript

For example, I have created some custom UI components, some depend on `jquery-min.js`, some depend on `jQuery UI`, some depend on `jsTree`, some depend on `Dojo`, etc.

I can import the required libraries in each xhtml files:

```
file1.xhtml
<script src="jquery-min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jsTree.js"></script>
<my:tree> ... </my:tree>

file2.xhtml
<script src="jquery-min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-dialog.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-autocompletion.js"></script>
<my:autodialog> ... </my:autodialog>

file3.xhtml
<script src="jquery-min.js"></script>
<script src="dojo.js"></script>
<my:dojostuff> ... </my:dojostuff>
```

This is very inconvenient, I have to know which component depends on which library, and the dependencies of the dependencies.

To put all dependencies in the template file will certainly make things simpler, but that will load too much scripts, and memory out in mobile phone.

So, is there something like "UIAutoOrganizedScriptsComponent"?

Should I use something like request-scoped hash set, which contains the dependencies filled by components used in the current request, like this?

```
static ThreadLocal<HashSet> requestScopedDependencies;
static Map<String, URL> libraryURLs;

MyTreeComponent extends UIOutput {
    // ...
    dependencies = requestScopeDependencies.get();
    dependencies.add("jstree");
}
```

Or, maybe I should search the Component DOM to find out where I can inject the <script>? like this:

```
MyTreeComponent extends UIOutput {
    // ...
    UIComponent scriptsContainer = getParent().getParent().getChildren()[2].getChildren()[3];

    // search if scriptsContainer already included the script...
    if (! included) {
        scriptsContainer.addElement("<script>...");
    }
}
```

Well, very clumsy. Is there any elegant resolution to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need something along the lines of [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to load the dependencies dynamically on the page.